# Does auto implemented properties have an implied set?

Tags: c#

I was expecting the assignment to `this.GetProp` to fail at compile time due to no `set` supported for the property. This code compiled just fine with VS2015 & NET461.

```
public class Example
{
    public Example(string val)
    {
        this.GetProp = val;
        this.GetSetProp = val;
    }

    public string GetProp { get; }
    public string GetSetProp { get; set; }
}
```

Is there are implied private access to the backing field in auto properties?

Comment: You can set a property's value in the constructor, even when it's getter-only, just like you can assign to `readonly` variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a newly introduced feature in C# 6.0. See the **C# 6.0 Language specification**, section *10.7.3 Automatically implemented properties*:

> If the auto-property has no set accessor, the backing field is
>   considered readonly (§10.5.2). Just like a readonly field, a
>   getter-only auto-property **can also be assigned to in the body of a
>   constructor** of the enclosing class. Such an assignment assigns
>   directly to the readonly backing field of the property.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: A bad copy from the correctly answered question (see duplicate)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The other answers do not even quote the official specs

Comment: @Adrian you're quite right, I've updated my answer on the other question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This is a getter-only auto-property introduced in C# 6. The backing field is implicitly declared as `readonly`, hence you can set it from the constructor.